# How do i send data to asp.net controller so that it can return a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

What I want to do is so simple, I'm still trying to learn ASP.NET with c# and MVC application but I'm just having a lot of difficulty getting a simple example to go through, then I can grow from it, here's how it goes:  I have a simple html5 form that's method is GET, the type is text and I basically want to submit a text into my mvc controller, once my controller get's it, I want it to output that string 'worked' through HTML5, how do I do this?

summary: string 'worked' --> html form --> c# controller --> html (view?)

here's what I got for my 'view' (Search.cshtml)

```
<form action="Home/Search" method="get">
<input type="text" name="q" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
```

ok, so far so good, if I input 'worked' nothing is going to happen unless I add more code, here's c# (HomeController.cs):

```
 public ActionResult Search(string q)
    {

        return this.View(q?); // so what exactly is View(q)? what is view returning?        }
```

okay so this is where I am confused, does my string go through and become stored in 'q'? and if so, how do I get this thing to use HTML5 to output something like

```
<p> q </p> <!-- q = 'worked' -->
```

Comment: You can simply write `return View((object)q)`. This means it will call the correct overload (the one expecting a model object), rather than the current one (expecting the path of the view).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, you are calling the `View(...)` method incorrectly.  The `View(...)` method expects the string parameter you're passing to be the path to the razor view you're trying to render.

A quick and simple way to pass the `q` variable from your controller to a view to be rendered is using `ViewBag`.

If you have a razor view named **/Views/Search.cshtml** you would do:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Search(string q)
  {
    ViewBag.Query = q;
    return View("~/Views/Search.cshtml");
  }
}
```

Then in **/Views/Search.cshtml** use it like this:

```
<p>@ViewBag.Query</p>
```

Comment: I like this answer a lot, are there any limitations to this? is there things I should know while using this?

Comment: @FluffyWuffy Yes. ViewBag is dynamic and untyped.  So if you make typos (for example mistype the name of a property), the compiler won't be able to catch your error;  you will only catch after a crash or unexpected behavior during runtime.  However, it's great for trying out ideas or small scale quick web-apps.

Answer (score 0):

Search.cshtml

```
<form action="/Home/Search" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="q" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<p class='current-query'>@Model</p>
```

HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult Search(string q)
{
    return View((object)q); // return the model to the view (a string)
}
```

Comment: nice, can you please explain 'class='current-query'>@Model</p>? what if q = 500? what if q = a list? what does 'current-query' mean? what is that? how is @Model used for other things? links are also appreciated, and thanks

Comment: Actually, what `@Model` does is to print `Model.ToString()`. If you pass a list, then you'll have to do `@foreach(var item in Model) { /*lines for each elem in list*/ }`

Comment: @FluffyWuffy, in a Razor template you can mix C# code with your HTML. Something like this `@foreac(var item in Model) { <div class='result'>@item</div> }`. Image this code as 3 separate lines...

Comment: This cannot work, It would need to be `return View((object)q);` or the wrong overload of `View()` will be called and an exceptionwill be thrown since `q` is a string

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp.net mvc, then please follow mvc pattern like this ..

View

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Search","Home",FormMethod.Post))
{
 <b>Name : </b>
 @Html.TextBox("searchTerm", null, new { @id = "txtSearch" })
 <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(string searchTerm)
    {
        return View(searchTerm);
    }
}
```