# Check (and prevent) for duplicate Date/Time entries

Tags: c#, sql, time, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a project for joining `SportEvent`s, where I want users to enter an `EventStart` and `EventEnd` using the `DateTime` type when creating an event. When a user tries to create an event within an already chosen `DateTime` value, I would like to prohibit the user from creating a new event.

These are some screenshots:

A method in the SportEventController

[image: img]

The properties of the SportEvent

[image: img2]

The .cshtml for setting the `DateTime` values

[image: img3]

The values are saved in a SQL-Database and I would like to check if a new `DateTime` value is between an existing `EventStart` and `EventEnd`

Comment: where is your sql query to check if a new DateTime value is between a existing EventStart and EventEnd?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I do not have a SQL query for this. I originally wanted to set the query, and thus the condition, in the if statement in my SportEventController.

Comment: Just an FYI, posting screenshots of code makes it harder for someone to help you. Instead, type it into the question itself (using code formatting), so that answers can read and copy it more easily.

Comment: @jpaugh thanks for your tips! I really value all the information you gave me, I will  try to work out the overlapping date range checker.

Comment: You're welcome! Ultimately, you could implement the date-checking in a stored procedure (to which maSTAShuFu alluded), and simply fail the transaction if the date range is invalid; however, it might well be easier to do in C#, with the downside of being would be somewhat slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the question has changed from a SQL query to find conflicts, to locating them in code and acting upon them.

I'm unsure what BadRequest and Ok do, you're missing a code layer.  But you should have success handling and error handling in your ajax or php or whatever called
your action result method.  I would recommend on failure you provide a meaningful alert to the user based on the failure reason.  So if it is a schedule conflict
they can change schedule info, if they were missing data elements they can fill them in, or if the save failed you can handle that in a meaningful way.

See if this helps get you going in the right direction:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DoNotNameItPost([FromBody] SportEvent sportEvent)
{
    if(sportEvent != null)
    {
        // you should probably just have 1 of these for your controller but we'll use local instantiation for the example
        SportEventService ses = new SportEventService();

        // your service should have a db connection that simply gets all your sportevents.
        // I would recommend having a where clause that eliminates events that have already happend
        // from the result set.  thus "upcoming" instead of "existing" events
        List<SportEvent> upcomingEvents = ses.GetUpcomingEventsToList();

        bool conflict = false;

        foreach(SportEvent se in upcomingEvents)
        {
            // logic:  if the new BEGINS before existing ENDS
            // OR new ENDS AFTER existing BEGINS there is a conflict
            // OR if the new event completely encompasses an existing one
            if( (sportEvent.EventStart < se.EventEnd) || (sportEvent.EventEnd > se.EventStart) || (sportEvent.EventStart < se.EventStart && sportEvent.EventEnd > se.EventEnd) )
            {
                conflict = true;
                // break if you find 1 conflict, no need to find more than 1
                break;
            }
        }

        // success condition
        if(!conflict)
        {
            // try to perform your save
            if(_sportEventManager.Save(sportEvent))
            {
                return Ok(sportEvent);
            }
            else
            {
                BadRequest("Save failed");
            }

        }
        // fail condition
        else
        {
            return BadRequest ("Schedule Conflict");
        } 
    }
    else
    {
         return BadRequest ("Invalid SportEvent Data");
    }
}
```

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for exactly.
What you are missing from the code shown in the question are 3 fold.
One:  you are missing an action of some kind on your cshtml.
Two:  That action will go to controller directly or utilize php or javascript to perform an ajax call.
Three: How to handle your response.  The ajax call should pass your new sport event, and expect to receive a success or error with a message.  According to the code above.

Do you need help with that part?  Or just the logic of filtering if results have a schedule conflict?  Or both?

The answers provided here were in regards to identifying your schedule conflicts.  If you need help going from your .cshtml to your ajax to your controller and then receiving the response and acting on it, that is a separate question all together.

Here is a very simple example without use of javascript, php, or ajax.  If this is your question you may wish to make a new one and be clear that is what you're asking.  [How do i send data to asp.net controller so that it can return a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37244644/how-do-i-send-data-to-asp-net-controller-so-that-it-can-return-a-view)

I would highly recommend finding a cshtml tutorial and just going through the steps.  Once you see the pattern you can move that right over to your app and it will make more sense each time you need to do it.

Comment: Hey, I know the most rude thing on SO to do, is to ask for code but I just realised I provided the API controller. Please do not get me wrong by my question since I really value your input, but could you present the same methods you used in this controller,for the controller that is responsible for the POST to the database.
https://jsfiddle.net/3hk61u1u/

Comment: I added a lengthy response to my answer.  If none of that is what you're looking for and you need help building a service to connect to your db and run your sql query, that again is another question.  Here is a very good answer on connecting your app to your database: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562348/connect-to-database-c-sharp

Comment: I have 2 controllers in my application, 1 for my Database, and 1 for the API. The one I send you, thus the one you changed in this answer ^, is for the API. That is the wrong one, I wondered if you could change the code I send in my last answer like you did for the API controller so I can use the correct controller when adding events. It is in the jsfiddle link i added in my last response.

Answer (score 1):

When creating new event, you can search for existing events for overlapping date periods with (pseudo-sql):

```
Select * from events e where EventStart < @end and EventEnd > @start
```

Where @start and @end are dates for new Event. If query gives results, it means that periods overlap at least partly, then just prevent new event creation.

**Update**: Event if [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48410068/5789864) doubts, this sql helps you getting situations where timespans overlaps partly or completely, no matter how. Take your time and simulate different cases on paper so this solution opens to you.

Comment: I cannot comment on [Accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48410458/5789864), but it seems that it does not find case, where there exists event on days 5.-6. and you are creating new one on dates 4.-7. This sql returns all events which overlaps between new event's start and end: completely and partly and both ways.

Comment: I think I understand your answer. You are saying that when an event will be longer than an existing event , it will **not** be BETWEEN already existing `EventStart` and `EventEnd` because it just falls outside the old event? I could potentially add the NOT BETWEEN statements after the 2 BETWEEN ones.

Comment: Yes, you ubderstood the problem right. This my solution handles also that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48410068/712526) posted is that it will only return if the new event is completely contained within the time frame for an existing one.

Try instead:

```
SELECT * FROM Events WHERE ((newStart BETWEEN Start AND End) OR (newEnd BETWEEN Start AND End)) OR (newStart < Start AND newEnd > End)
```

If you want to be really fancy you could load a calendar into your UI with the existing events.  This could force your users to select a time not already chosen and thus prevent the check altogether (as well as prevent having to return "error - time already in use" and "please try again" messages to your user).

Comment: I totally overlooked the query only checking dates completely within other events. I do have a calender via `DateTime` but I want to have to core functions working before I add 'details'. Thanks in advance already!

Comment: @user Please include a link to the answer you're referring to (available via the *share* button), as it can get confusing when multiple answers are posted (perhaps later), and when the order of answers change (which happens all the time). Usernames can be changed freely, too; so even that's not always enough to figure it out.

Comment: FYI, While another might have posted this as a comment, it is an answer, and your contribution was viewed as necessary to the OP. You can make it independent of the original answer by explaining what it does (not only what it does differently from another answer). As long as you still give credit to the first answer, this is acceptable.

Comment: Your sql query does not handle situation where there exists previously created event on days 5.-6. and user is creating new one on dates 4.-7. My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48410068/5789864) handles this as well as every other overlapping situations.

Comment: datetime values handle timespans that encompass midnght.  Your sql looked for the entire event to fall within the timespan of an existing event.  The sql in this answer looks for the events overlapping at all.  But I do see the case that is missed.  Where a new event completely encompasses and existing one.  Good catch.

Comment: @user7396598 I disagree. My sql do not require entire event to fall within timespan of an existing event. If you look very carefully my sql's where condition: EventStart < newEnd and EventEnd > newStart. It checks if there is any portion of time to overlap.